# How can I sum the values in one column based on the floor'd value of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some sales data (shown below) that has a variety of different price points. In many cases, the items will be sold at very similar prices, e.g. 79.98 and 79.99.  What I want to do though is sum the visits and sales for items that all exist within the same dollar amount (i.e. the floor), but also retain the original price, because I will need to use that as a key to perform a join against later. For example, using the data shown below:

```
    product  price visits sales conversion
29  12345678  74.98    225    14     0.0622
30  12345678  79.98    302    12     0.0397
31  12345678  79.99    446    19     0.0426
32  12345678  81.98     17     1     0.0588
33  12345678  84.98     11     0     0.0000
34  12345678  84.99    845    52     0.0615
35  12345678  88.98     96     8     0.0833
36  12345678  88.99     81     0     0.0000
37  12345678  89.99    324    13     0.0401
38  12345678  92.98    234     2     0.0085
39  12345678  93.98     97     0     0.0000
40  12345678  94.98      5     0     0.0000
41  12345678  99.99   1069    11     0.0103
```

product, selling_price, floor(selling_price), sum(visits), sum(sales)

```
product, selling_price, floored_price, total_visits, total_sales
12345678, 79.98, 79.00, 527, 26
12345678, 79.99, 79.99, 527, 26
```

The last part of this, is I want to do this with pandas for a variety of reasons that I don't have much control over. Any ideas?

Comment: Ca nyou explain more `floored_price` column values in output of sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
pd.merge_asof(df, \
              df.assign(floored_price=df.price.apply(np.floor)). \
                 groupby('floored_price')[['sales', 'visits']].sum(). \
                 rename(columns={'sales':'total_sales', 'visits':'total_visits'}). \
                 reset_index(), \
              left_on='price', right_on='floored_price')

#     product  price  visits  sales  conversion  floored_price  total_sales  total_visits
# 0  12345678  74.98     225     14      0.0622           74.0           14           225
# 1  12345678  79.98     302     12      0.0397           79.0           31           748
# 2  12345678  79.99     446     19      0.0426           79.0           31           748
# 3  12345678  81.98      17      1      0.0588           81.0            1            17
# 4  12345678  84.98      11      0      0.0000           84.0           52           856
```